# why different processors can give different max speed up for multithreading programs?

Tags: multithreading, cpu

I implemented a multithreaded program for matrix multiplication and serial program for same I observed that on my laptop multithreaded program giving speedup up to 4 compared serial one but. when I ran the same program on another computer it was giving max speedup of 2 so what is the reason behind it does CPU cores affect speedup and can dual-core CPU never give speedup more than 2?

Comment: probably because your code is memory-bound on one machine and not the other since two machine can have different memory throughput (cache en RAM). A good big matrix multiplication is fully compute bound on any modern computer. Try to compare your algorithm with BLAS like OpenBLAS, the MKL or BLIS and see if you could reproduce this effect (probably not).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the "real world" performance improvement for multithreading I can expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654432/whats-the-real-world-performance-improvement-for-multithreading-i-can-expect)